# Java SOAP WS client fails from command line, works in Eclipse (shocking, right?)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, soap

I am developing a WS client that will need to use MTOM for some data transfer. However, I have a different problem and it's driving me nuts. It involves, of course, running the JAR file from the command line.

I used cxf-codegen-plugin to generate the classes from WSDL and built a simple client. I created a MockService in SoapUI with that same WSDL and tested the client against it. Needless to say, everything works perfectly from Eclipse. I used maven-assembly-plugin to create a single JAR and when I run it from the command line, I get an exception as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager.getDefinition(String)" because the return value of "org.apache.cxf.Bus.getExtension(java.lang.Class)" is null
       at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:217)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:160)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
       at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
       at com.xxx.xmldefs.sup.enterpriseservices.documentmanagementservice.v1.DocumentManagementService.<init>(DocumentManagementService.java:43)
       at XXX.MTOMClient.MTOMClient.main(MTOMClient.java:53)
```

Obviously, something is missing in my dependencies, build path, libraries, whatnot, since from Eclipse, client connects, executes the call and gets the result back. I have Maven dependencies and Java system libraries checked in the "Order and Export" section of the project build path.

What am I missing? I admit not to be an expert, I develop things in Java occassionally so maybe this is something simple I just haven't come across yet.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have all the needed dependencies inside your jar file? If you unzip it.  
What version of cxf are you using?

Comment: Dependencies are there, I'm not getting a "ClassNotFound" exception. I'm using v3.1.11 of CXF.

Comment: As far as the code goes, it is failing getBus().getExtension(WSDLManager.class) <-- This is returning null to you.   How is your bus initialized?

Comment: I don't do any explicit initialization in the code. I create a new web service client based on the classes generated by CXF. That code works perfectly fine when I run it in Eclipse but fails with the exception above when I call my "fat JAR" from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this issue ... the problem is in the fact that creating a fat JAR can lead to different reference/configuration files being ignored, if maven-assembly-plugin is used. It always produces a single e.g. META-INF/cfx/bus-extensions.txt file, which was a problem in this case.

The solution is to use maven-shade-plugin and then apply a transformer called AppendingTransformer to this particular file. Shade has multiple transformers that might be needed in your project. Below you can find the one that worked for me:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>XXX.YYY.ZZZ</mainClass>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The *exclude* section is needed to handle signed JARs, as creating a fat JAR will invalidate them and JVM will complain.